# Linq where clause based on different bool condition C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi i'm trying to filter a list of items based on multiple bool parameters.
I have 3 bool parameters (they are 3 checkbox in the UI): **IsTypeA**, **IsTypeB**, **IsTypeC**.
Based on this 3 values i have to filter my list on a enum property of the items (called simply "Type").
Multiple checkbox can be checked.
There's also another filter ("in", "out") above the type filter, but that is working.
What i've tried so far is this:

```
FilteredDashboardItems = AllItems?.Where(x => 
                    Destination == "in" ?
                    (
                        (IsTypeA == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A : true)                    
                        &&
                        (IsTypeB == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.B : true)                    
                        &&
                        (IsTypeC == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.C : true)                    
                    ) : 
                    Destination == "out" ?
                    (
                        (IsTypeA == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A : true)                    
                        &&
                        (IsTypeB == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.B : true)                    
                        &&
                        (IsTypeC == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.C : true)                    
                    ) : true)?.ToList();
```

Problem is: if i singularly check a checkbox (let's say IsTypeA), the list gets correctly filtered for A Type items. But if i check another checkbox (let's say IsTypeB) instead of showing me A + B types filtered list, the list returns 0 items.
How can i solve that?

Comment: Do your `&&` need to be `||` ?

Comment: Is it really possible that `AllItems` is `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
    List<int> typesToCheck = new List<int>();

    if (IsTypeA) typesToCheck.Add((int)Helpers.A);
    if (IsTypeB) typesToCheck.Add((int)Helpers.B);
    if (IsTypeC) typesToCheck.Add((int)Helpers.C);

    FilteredDashboardItems = AllItems?.Where(x => Destination == "in" ?
        (IsTypeA || IsTypeB || IsTypeC ? typesToCheck.Contains(x.Type) : true)
        :
        Destination == "out" ?
            (IsTypeA || IsTypeB || IsTypeC ? typesToCheck.Contains(x.Type) : true)
            : 
            true)?.ToList();
```

And once you get it to this form, I'm sure you can also simplify the Destination conditions

Comment: Thank you, the logic of this was much easier and worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You are using && And that will give you an Intersection of the both filter hence the 0 records.

You need to use OR || so that it shows element that satisfy either of the the filter.

Comment: If i used || instead of && the query didn't filter at all. I ended up using Paul solution to use the "contains" for the enums.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is little bit weird

```
IsTypeA == true ? x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A : true
```

If **IsTypeA** is not **nullable bool**, then no need to compare it with **true**, because logically you get **true == true** or **false == true**, so you can just leave **IsTypeA**.

I would rewrite your condition:

```cs
FilteredDashboardItems = AllItems?.Where(x => 
                    Destination == "in" ?
                    (
                        (IsTypeA && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A)                    
                        ||
                        (IsTypeB && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.B)                    
                        ||
                        (IsTypeC && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.C)                    
                    ) : 
                    Destination == "out" ?
                    (
                        (IsTypeA && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A)                    
                        ||
                        (IsTypeB && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.B)                    
                        ||
                        (IsTypeC && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.C)                    
                    ) : true)?.ToList();
```

Now we have simple logic: if at least on of the selected types is equal to object type then keep this object

Comment: Yes, but the main fix is to use `||`

Comment: If i used || instead of && the query doesn't filter at all

Answer (score 0):

In this type of question, In case the list has a lot of items,
I will recommend to write Linq As QUERY, and not as Method.

```
(from item in AllItems
let firstCondition =  (IsTypeA && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.A) 
let secCondition =  (IsTypeB && x.Type == Helpers.Enum.B)
where firstCondition && secCondition
select item)?.ToList();
```

when you write in that form you create tmp Variable in the let section and save Time, more than that I believe that form is more readable in complex logics.

Comment: Thank you, i resolved using Paul solution. I had to use lambda because i was filtering directly inside a foreach loop, but this was a nice way too that i'll consider for the future

Comment: By the way you can do it inside foreach, just create linq query that wrap all the current query. Very love to help